# Input Box Calculator does not change result value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make a Calculator with Input boxes.

This is my code and for some reason it doesnt change the result box value!

As you can see I tried both `.val("result")` and `.attr("value","result")`
Both don't work.

Some help would be really nice!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Praktikum Webanwendungen</title>
    <style>
      input,
      button {
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#b1").click(function(){
                Add();
            });
            $("#b2").click(function(){
                Substract();
            });
            $("#b3").click(function(){
                Multiply();
            });
            $("#b4").click(function(){
                Divide();
            });
        });
        function Add(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1+no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").attr("value","result")
        }    
        function Substract(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1-no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result)    
        }    
        function Multiply(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1*no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val("result")    
        }    
        function Divide(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1/no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val("result") 
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Taschenrechner</h1>
    <label for="num1">Zahl1: </label>
    <input id="number1" name="num1" type="number" />

    <label for="num2">Zahl2: </label>
    <input id="number2" name="num2" type="number" />

    <div>
      <button id="b1">+</button>
      <button id="b2">-</button>
      <button id="b3">x</button>
      <button id="b4">/</button>
    </div>

    <label for="res">Ergebnis: </label>
    <input id="ergebnis" name="res" type="number" value = "" >
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are passing result variable in double quotes. remove double quotes.

Comment: Still does not work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your script tag. I have updated your code please check

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Praktikum Webanwendungen</title>
    <style>
      input,
      button {
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#b1").on('click',function(){
                Add();
            });
            $("#b2").on('click',function(){
                Substract();
            });
            $("#b3").on('click',function(){
                Multiply();
            });
            $("#b4").on('click',function(){
                Divide();
            });
        });
        function Add(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1+no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result)
        }    
        function Substract(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1-no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result)    
        }    
        function Multiply(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1*no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result)    
        }    
        function Divide(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1/no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result) 
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Taschenrechner</h1>
    <label for="num1">Zahl1: </label>
    <input id="number1" name="num1" type="number" />

    <label for="num2">Zahl2: </label>
    <input id="number2" name="num2" type="number" />

    <div>
      <button id="b1">+</button>
      <button id="b2">-</button>
      <button id="b3">x</button>
      <button id="b4">/</button>
    </div>

    <label for="res">Ergebnis: </label>
    <input id="ergebnis" name="res" type="number" value = "" >
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. You have to close the script tag of Jquery after importing it and then open a new `<script>` tag for your code. Also, the double-quotes can interfere with the output.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Praktikum Webanwendungen</title>
    <style>
      input,
      button {
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#b1").click(function(){
                Add();
            });
            $("#b2").click(function(){
                Substract();
            });
            $("#b3").click(function(){
                Multiply();
            });
            $("#b4").click(function(){
                Divide();
            });
        });
        function Add(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1+no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result)
        }    
        function Substract(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1-no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result)    
        }    
        function Multiply(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1*no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result)    
        }    
        function Divide(){    
         var no1=parseInt($("#number1").val());    
         var no2=parseInt($("#number2").val());    
         var result =no1/no2;    
          $("#ergebnis").val(result) 
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Taschenrechner</h1>
    <label for="num1">Zahl1: </label>
    <input id="number1" name="num1" type="number" />

    <label for="num2">Zahl2: </label>
    <input id="number2" name="num2" type="number" />

    <div>
      <button id="b1">+</button>
      <button id="b2">-</button>
      <button id="b3">x</button>
      <button id="b4">/</button>
    </div>

    <label for="res">Ergebnis: </label>
    <input id="ergebnis" name="res" type="number" value = "" >
  </body>
</html>
```